# Solve the following quadratic equation: $4\tan^2(\theta)x^4-4x^2+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$$4\tan^2(\theta)x^4-4x^2+1=0$$

It can be seen that as $\theta$ goes to $0$, the leftmost term disappears and $x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$.

But when I try to solve this using the quadratic formula I get:

$$x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-\tan^2(\theta)}}{2\tan^2(\theta)}}$$

In this expression as $\theta$ goes to $0$ the denominator goes to zero.

I guess there may be a way of manipulating this expression such that as $\theta$ goes to zero $x$ goes to $\pm 0.5$.

How could this expression be manipulated?

Comment: $1-\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta}$ goes to $0$ too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your question can be reformulated to

> What is $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\sqrt{\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-\tan^2(\theta)}}{2\tan^2(\theta)}}$$

To calculate that, first of all, since $\sqrt{}$ is a continuous function, all you need to do is to caluclate 
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-\tan^2(\theta)}}{2\tan^2(\theta)}$$
and take the square root.

---

This limit has two distinct possibilities:

**The first**:

Taking the plus sign makes $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{1+ \sqrt{1-\tan^2(\theta)}}{2\tan^2(\theta)} = \infty$$

which makes sense because, as $\theta$ becomes small **but not zero**, two of the roots of your polynomial become larger and larger.

**The second**:

We can introduce a new variable $y=\tan(\theta)$ and get

$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{1- \sqrt{1-\tan^2(\theta)}}{2\tan^2(\theta)} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{2y^2}$$

which can easily be calculated either by using L'Hospital or by seeing that
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{2y^2} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{2y^2}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}} = \frac{1-(1-y^2)}{2y^2(1+\sqrt{1-y^2})} =\\=\frac{y^2}{2y^2(1+\sqrt{1-y^2})} = \frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{1-y^2})}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta}}{2\tan^2\theta}
= \lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta})(1+\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta})}{(2\tan^2\theta)(1+\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta})} = \lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\tan^2\theta}{(2\tan^2\theta)(1+\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta})}=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta})}=\frac{1}{2}$$